# How to make Zurb Foundation Reveal modal popup slide up

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am using the Zurb Foundation Reveal modal popup. I have a requirement to have the modal popup appear by sliding up from the bottom, but by default, it only slides down.

I am using Foundation 4.0.

Any help is greatly appreciated.